# Adding to a map in DynamoDB (using Node.js) without knowing ID

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

[Reading through the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.AddingListsAndMaps), AWS seem to imagine that you somehow know the index numbering of a map that you’re updating. Which is odd, because they don’t even use the numbers in their interface.

I have this object:

```
let zoo = {
  camels: 562
}
```

And I’d like to add it to my item:

```
{
  Key: { id: id },
  TableName: tableName,
  UpdateExpression:
    'SET #z = :z',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#z': 'zoo'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':z': zoo
  }
}
```

All good so far. Now I’ve been given a new item to append to the list. It could be more than one:

```
let zoo = {
  elephants: 126,
  tigers: 89
}
```

And then my goal is to get my `zoo` map to look like this:

```
{
  camels: 562,
  elephants: 126,
  tigers: 89
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to append to a map without an ID.

I saw somebody using this:

```
'SET #z = #z + :z'
```

But that didn’t work at all (`Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: +, operand type: M`).

AWS’s docs would suggest that I could do something like this:

```
'SET #z.#animal = :animal'
```

And then I could possibly loop through my object and generate a `SET` string that would work. However, this is just a basic example of what I’m trying to do. I would like to be able to add something like this:

```
let zoo = {
  aquatics: {
    penguins: 988,
    tropical_fish: 1943
  },
  mammals: {
    elephants: 126,
    tigers: 89 
  }
}
```

I could of course get the item first, merge the map in JavaScript, and then send it back again – but I’m trying to avoid having to make a read/write request.

Comment: The way I read it, the documentation you cited, where it speaks of indexes, refers to lists -- not maps.

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific, was referring to ‘Adding Nested Map Attributes’ where it uses `SET #pr.#5star[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use ADD?

```
{
  Key: { id: id },
  TableName: tableName,
  UpdateExpression:
    'ADD #z = :z',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#z': 'zoo'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":z": "L": ["M": {"Elephants": {"N": 126}}]
  }
}
```

> If the attribute is a set, and the value you are adding is also a set,
>   then the value is appended to the existing set.

I think the key thing here is the value you are adding must be a set. Am I right in thinking you have a list of maps? In which case, add a list of maps containing one map.